# Ropsten contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: solidity, transactions

Can someone help me and  tell me where in my code is the problem. How to fix this ?

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xbd2079c12f90bb9396d79e7aeb5b5914472dd25c9e62ce36ffa85f6e88d7b594

Is there any obvious error ?
Help is more than appreciate.Robert

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your code?

Comment: So this is my code. I try to do a test and send ether to the crowdsale contract and get back the right value of my tokens. I hope is easy to fix. I'm not a programmer. Any help from You is really appreciate.Robert

Comment: My code: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4927f2add565f2fa9e40c5cf0c826cc94eac60a4#code

Answer (score 0):

When sending ether to the contract address it would call this function in your contract:

```
function () payable whenNotPaused beforeDeadline afterStartTime saleNotClosed  {
    require(msg.value >= minContribution);

    // Update the sender's balance of wei contributed and the amount raised
    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint currentBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = currentBalance.add(amount);
    amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

    // Compute the number of tokens to be rewarded to the sender
    // Note: it's important for this calculation that both wei
    // and PDT have the same number of decimal places (18)
    uint numTokens = amount.mul(rate);

    // Transfer the tokens from the crowdsale supply to the sender
    if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)) {
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
        // Check if the funding goal or cap have been reached
        // TODO check impact on gas cost
        checkFundingGoal();
        checkFundingCap();
    }
    else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

The transaction would be reverted if either:

- contract is paused
- after deadline
- before start time
- sale is closed
- value is less than minimum contribution
- funding goal or cap has been reached

Comment: Thanks Koukotsu ! --Thanks to you, I see the problem more clearly,but this solves the problem partially, I need to do a test. I understand that there is no error ! and a modification of the payable function is needed to make test ?

Comment: Did the token owner authorized your contract to be able to make transfers? ie, `token.approve("0x4927f2ad....", amount, { from: "0xOwnerAddress" });`

Comment: Hello Ismael,  thank you for being interested in my problem. I think the problem lies in the message -gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction ,when I try to transfer ether to crowdsale contract here:https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xdf2dfda76fab2d3f6cf25eaebbdb0d7c0ff88f89#code